# Differentiate Android Phones Connected to a WLAN

Tags: android, network-monitoring

I understand that an android phone has an IP and MAC address, just like any other device, that can be seen when connected to a network. However, is there any way to differentiate an android phone from other devices connected to a network such as a WLAN?

Answer (score 2):

Using plain ethernet, not. There's no data in an ethernet packet that says "this packet brought to you by Intel" or the like. At most you can look at the MAC address. The first 16 bits of that are the manufacturer ID, but that'd only tell you who made the ethernet chip. It may not say "Samsung" or "HTC" at all.

You'd need to use something [nmap](https://nmap.org/) to do TCP stack sniffing to try and guess the OS running behind the scenes.